# jquery popup window won't close with keypress but will onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, popupwindow

I am having an annoying problem right now with jquery. before i explain it let me give you my code:

```
/***************************/
//@Author: Adrian "yEnS" Mato Gondelle
//@website: www.yensdesign.com
//@email: yensamg@gmail.com
//@license: Feel free to use it, but keep this credits please!                  
/***************************/

//SETTING UP OUR POPUP
//0 means disabled; 1 means enabled;
var popupStatus = 0;

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup($contact_selector){
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        }).fadeIn("slow");

        $contact_selector.fadeIn("slow");

        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}
//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup($contact_selector){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $contact_selector.fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

//centering popup
function centerPopup($contact_selector){
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("body").height();
    var popupWidth = $("body").width();
    //centering
    $contact_selector.css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
    });
    //only need force for IE6

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });

}

//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){   
    //LOADING POPUP
    //Click the button event!
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup($('#popupContact1'));
        //load popup
        loadPopup($('#popupContact1'));
    });
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup($('#popupContact2'));
        //load popup
        loadPopup($('#popupContact2'));
    });
    $("#button3").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup($('#popupContact3'));
        //load popup
        loadPopup($('#popupContact3'));
    });
    $("#button4").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup($('#popupContact4'));
        //load popup
        loadPopup($('#popupContact4'));
    }); 
    $("#button5").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup($('#popupContact5'));
        //load popup
        loadPopup($('#popupContact5'));
    });
    $("#button6").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup($('#popupContact6'));
        //load popup
        loadPopup($('#popupContact6'));
    });                 
    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    $("#popupContactClose1").click(function(){
    disablePopup($('#popupContact1'));
});
    $("#popupContactClose2").click(function(){
    disablePopup($('#popupContact2'));
});
    $("#popupContactClose3").click(function(){
    disablePopup($('#popupContact3'));
});
    $("#popupContactClose4").click(function(){
    disablePopup($('#popupContact4'));
});
    $("#popupContactClose5").click(function(){
    disablePopup($('#popupContact5'));
});
    $("#popupContactClose6").click(function(){
    disablePopup($('#popupContact6'));
});
    //Click out event!
    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        disablePopup(this);
    });
    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact1'));
    }
});
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact2'));
    }
});
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact3'));
    }
});
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact4'));
    }
});
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact5'));
    }
});
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact6'));
    }
});

});
```

so the problem is that when i try to use the keypress function to fadeout the div, only the background fades out leaving the div floating over the content pane. What is particularly weird is that the first instance of the code allows the fadeout on esc keypress but none of the others.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Edit1: I realize that only the first $(document) call is working

```
    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact1'));
    }
});
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact2'));
    }
});
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact3'));
    }
});
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact4'));
    }
});
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact5'));
    }
});
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
        disablePopup($('#popupContact6'));
    }
});

});
```

everything after the first call the background div fades and the text box is left over the container. If i switch the order of these calls and put disablePopup[($('#popupContact2')) before the disablePopup[($('#popupContact1')) then popupContact1 is left int he container on keypress but not popupContact2

edit: i realize that this question is a bit of a mess so I tried to be more clear in my execution. 
if you would like to continue to figure out the problem please see the new question at the following link:
[jquery popup window won't close on keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125964/jquery-popup-window-wont-close-on-keypress)

edit2: this was resolved - pointy suggested i add a class to each of the items i need to clse and just have the js close all open popups - worked like a charm thank you all for your help

Comment: Try the `keyup` event instead of `keypress`...

Comment: Why you have `popupStatus` cheching in `on keypress` function? You already have it in `disablePopup`, right?

Comment: And also... My eyes!!! Why just not use one `disablePopup` and `loadPopup` function and just pass different selectors to it since they do same things?

Comment: Indeed, some refactoring is needed urgently! :)

Comment: yeah i was hacking apart a code i found and i want to clean it all up when i get it to work :P sorry about that 

you are also right that I have two checks of popStatus - do you think this could cause the error?

Comment: @user1098860 try to clean code first, and then we try to fix it

Comment: @neoascetic do you think you could point me in the right direction to cleaning up my code - i don't need much just a little push or something to search for in google

Comment: @neoascetic I have attempted to change my code as you had suggested

Comment: My eyes, again! Try to remove duplicates from your code and change `id` to selectors! Like [so](http://jsfiddle.net/E3uvK/)

Comment: @neoascetic haha sorry to burn your eyes out again i have made the changes again

Comment: Do you create a new account for every question you ask? A search for "www.yensdesign.com" leads multiple questions each having low reps, and different users. I'm not trying to be a detective, but it is just something I noticed

Comment: @RPM Yeah that might be the case and if so, I dont mean for it to be - in my account page i can see each of the questions I have been asking. Is there something wrong with this? I think it is because I use google to log in

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with it I didn't mean to call you out on it.

Comment: @RPM i added a username so you can see me as i ask all sorts of questions lol :P

Comment: Be aware that you cannot really expect a Javascript code with a console error to work.  The interpreter stops executing when it finds the error, and your code, from the error on, is ignored.
It doesn't really matter that the cause of the error is not related to the symptom you are seeing.

Comment: i believe i am no longer getting any errors in my js (when i run the code no errors appear in firebug console) thanks sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a class to each id and used that to close instead - this worked like a charm

snackerfish

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery docs, you shouldn't be using `.keyCode`, but `.which`

I got that from http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which==27){
    disablePopup($('#popupContact2'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Check out the new answer, I think I found the problem

Comment: You really need to use .wich instead of .keyCode, or you will never be sure if your code will continue working in every different browser in the future.

Comment: I changed all of the keypress to which but the problem still occurs. Do you think it could have something to do with the $(document) part? or should i use the $("#popupContactClose1") as i did for the .click

Comment: actually with .which, the escape keypress isnt recognized at all and nothing happens

Comment: Which is the value you get in which? Can you add a breakpoint and check it? By pressing a letter, and by pressing Esc

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
$("#popupContactClose6").keypress(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
                disablePopup6();
            }
        });
```

You forgot a closing " ...

**Edit:**

Try doing it differently:

```
$('#backgroundPopup, #popupContact6').fadeOut("slow");
```

Use the `keyup` event instead of `keypress` to get the `ESC` key working as expected, like this:

```
$("#popupContactClose6").keyup(function(e) {

            if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1) {

                disablePopup6();
            }
});

function disablePopup6() {

       $('#backgroundPopup, #popupContact6').fadeOut("slow");

        popupStatus = 0;
}
```

Comment: So your `disablePopup6` function is being called correctly but only the `$("#popupContact6").fadeOut("slow");` is not working...

Comment: actually the keypress is not working at all but i am using the same theory for keypress as i did for click so i thought it would work

Comment: This is really weird since the same method works when it's called from the click event...

Comment: still have the same problem - when i press esc nothing happens (nothing in console either) i dont think the escp press is being recognized at all

Comment: unfortunately this solution did not work - it actually made it so that even the first div (disablePopup1) would not fade out. thank you